# Главная категория Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Как определить главную категорию товара? Код ниже определяет (к примеру) телефоны -> ***смартфоны***, а мне нужно что бы определяло ***телефоны*** -> смартфоны

```
$product_category = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_id);
foreach ($product_category as $prodcat)
{
    $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($prodcat['category_id']);
    if ($category_info)
    {
        $podcatname = $category_info['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: сам не сообразишь, никто не поможет `$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
  $categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_info['product_id']);
  if ($categories){
  $categories_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($categories[0]['category_id']);
  $this->data['category_id'] = $categories_info['name'];
  }`

Comment: Это стоит оформить в виде ответа. [answer]